# Split overlapping date ranges into mutliple date ranges using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I would like to know if its possible to split a given date ranges into separate date ranges if some certain criteria is met?

For example,

### FromDate   |  ToDate    | Season

```
2018-09-19 | 2019-09-30 | winter
2018-09-25 | 2018-09-30 | mugaram
2018-10-01 | 2018-10-31 | dewali
2018-12-24 | 2018-12-28 | Christmas
2018-12-31 | 2019-01-03 | New year
2019-02-01 | 2019-02-28 | peak
2019-02-20 | 2019-02-28 | peak
```

And the output should be something like this,

### FromDate   |  ToDate    | Season

```
2018-09-19 | 2018-09-24 | winter
2018-09-25 | 2018-09-30 | mugaram
2018-10-01 | 2018-10-31 | dewali
2018-11-01 | 2018-12-23 | winter
2018-12-24 | 2018-12-28 | Christmas
2018-12-31 | 2019-01-03 | New year
2018-01-04 | 2019-01-19 | winter
2019-02-01 | 2019-02-19 | peak
2019-02-20 | 2019-02-28 | peak
2018-03-01 | 2019-09-30 | winter
```

I have tried

```
SELECT FromDate,ToDate,SeasonName,
        DATEDIFF(ToDate,FromDate) as ranges 
FROM table 
order by DATEDIFF(ToDate,FromDate) asc
```

Comment: Ni Neethu, welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please show us the code you've been trying to use already so we can help you fix it?

Comment: SELECT FromDate,ToDate,SeasonName ,DATEDIFF(ToDate,FromDate) as ranges FROM table order by DATEDIFF(ToDate,FromDate) asc

Comment: Your question is really not clear! And WHAT CRITERIA?

Comment: using myql query i have to split the date ranges in the example as shown in the output. I have tried the above mentioned query, but its not the correct solution. Is there any others solutions to solve this?

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: What I need is a mysql query to get output like mentioned

Comment: Where does 2018-11-01 come from?

Comment: And presumably '2018-01-04 | 2019-01-19 | winter' is either wrong, or in the wrong place ?!?!?!

Comment: I have a mysql table season with fields and data as mentioned in the example, and some of the dates of seasons overlap with others, what i need is  split that overlappinng dates into other date ranges as shown in the sample output. Can anybody help?

Comment: Hi strawberry, the input winter season is long date range and its dates overlap with others so its split into 4 times in the sample output.